# Searching for nearest regions by name in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I'd like to implement autocomplete suggestions for regions near to the user. So for a user located in San Francisco that enters "Union Sq", it might suggest "Union Square, SF" and then Union Square, NY". This is backed by a table of regions that includes the name, the centroid, and the geometry. The size of the table will be around 500k entries with a standard (lexical) index on name and a 2dsphere index on centroid. How do I implement this in a performant way?

Using the query below, MongoDB always seems to use the geospatial index, which results in > 1s running time.

```
{
    "name": {
        "$regex": "^Union Sq"
    },
    "centroid": { 
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.39986, 37.75716] }
        }
    }
}
```

If I limit the results to a 100 mile radius using $maxDistance, the performance increases significantly, but then I would need a system of making a secondary non-performant query using $minDistance if the user were targeting a region further out. I suppose I could implement the UI so that secondary queries were purely lexical, which would allow the user to eventually find distant regions once they had typed in enough of the region name, but a near-sort on these names would be ideal.

Using the query below, MongoDB seems to perform pretty well if the suggestions are close, but when it needs to pull from further regions to satisfy the limit, the performance degrades somewhat.

```
regions = await Region.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: "Point", coordinates: [-122.39986, 37.75716]
            },
            key: "centroid",
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            query: {
                name: { $regex: '^Union Sq' }
            }
        }
    },
    { $limit: 5 }
]);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Secondary questions include:

- Is it possible to make the MongoDB use the lexical index first and then sort those results geographically? MongoDB seems to always use the geo index no matter what in the first query above.
- This is certainly not critical, but ideally I'd like to use sort using the actual geometry instead of the centroid for more accurate results... Can this be done in a performant way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a better solution on MongoDB, but I just ported the data to Postgres and the first query above was lightning fast... not too mention a bunch of other benefits (e.g., MongoDB is super picky with polygons) . Also a helpful link for anyone in the same situation:

https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html